# Calling overridden method in Java

Tags: java, spring

I want to override the method written in the parent class. So I have written `ExtendDocumentLinkServiceImpl` to extended the parent class. But, when I execute it, it's still calling the parent `createDocumentLink()` method.

```
<bean name="documentLinkService" 
    class="org.xxxx.repo.doclink.ExtraDocumentLinkServiceImpl" init-method="init">
    <property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService"/>
</bean>


public class DocumentLinkServiceImpl implements DocumentLinkService {
    private NodeService nodeService;

    public void init() {
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "nodeService", nodeService);
    }

    @Override
    public NodeRef createDocumentLink(final NodeRef source, NodeRef destination) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Creating document link. source: " + source + ", destination: " + destination);
        }
    }

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }
}
```

---

```
<bean name="extendDocumentLinkService" class="com.xxxx.cms.doclink.ExtendDocumentLinkServiceImpl" parent="documentLinkService">
   <constructor-arg ref="nodeService"/>
</bean>


public class ExtendDocumentLinkServiceImpl extends DocumentLinkServiceImpl {
    private NodeService nodeService;

    public CustomizedDocumentLinkServiceImpl(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService=nodeService;
    }

    @Override
    public NodeRef createDocumentLink(final NodeRef source, NodeRef destination) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Creating document link. source: " + source + ", destination: " + destination);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add code where you "execute it, it's still calling the out-of-the-box", because I don't quite get what you're doing.

Comment: How do you know it's calling the wrong method? They are identical? Are you debugging?

Comment: I am debugging in eclipse.its always calling DocumentLinkServiceImpl's createDocumentLink method.

Comment: Please show us how you are referencing the instance and calling the method?

Comment: Maybe you are injecting base instance instead of extended one.

Comment: The class in the superclass bean def is ”ExtraDocumentLinkServiceImpl” so it looks like that there is a third class involved